# TCP Listener which should accept 100 threads per second

Tags: sockets, jmeter, load-testing, tcplistener

I have written code for TcpListener in c# which is supposed to receive request from client socket and process the request (send the processed request to our another web service to get final response) then parse the response and send the response back to client socket which initiated the request.

Code snippet below.

Code works fine when receive few requests at a time but now in order to move this to cloud and accept multiple request. We are testing this functionality by running JMeter test on same.

We are getting throughput like 4 when we hit 100 threads per seconds (end to end test - client system to server socket to our web service and back) which should be at least 30 to match client requirement.
If we omit the end to end flow and just send back to hardcode response from server socket itself we are seeing throughput 700.

To find the root cause I have added delay while sending hardcore response (same which we need to communicate with our web service) and I can see same behavior i.e. throughput drastically downgrades = 4/3.8

It means when TcpListener is busy processing existing request it may not attend the next requests (may be I am wrong in assumption - please correct if so)

Please have a look at code and help me increasing the performance .

```
public void StartTCPServer()
    {
        Logger.Write_Info_Log("In StartTCPServer - inPort : " + AESDK_CONFIG.PORT_NO, 1, log);
        try
        {
            // Data buffer for incoming data.
            byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

            // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, AESDK_CONFIG.PORT_NO);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.

            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true)
            {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
                listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener);

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Logger.Write_Fatal_Log("Exception in Start Listening : " + Ex.Message, 1, log);
        }
    }

    public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }

    public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        String strdata = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket. 
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
            // more data.
            strdata = state.sb.ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strdata))
            {
                // All the data has been read from the client. 
                if (strdata.Contains("<<CheckConnection>>"))
                {
                    log.Info(GlobalVar.gThreadNo(GlobalVar.gintCurrentThread) + "Data Received: " + strdata);
                    byte[] byData1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<<CheckConnectionAlive>>");
                    Send(handler, "<<CheckConnectionAlive>>");
                }
                else
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref m_clientCount);
                    //Process incoming requests here and send response back to client
                    string strResponse = GetRequest(strdata, m_clientCount);
                    Send(handler, strResponse);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Not all data received. Get more.
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this is some sort of forwarding... did you compare your performance to the performance of other forwarding implementations? Here is one I found, you could use to compare: http://blog.brunogarcia.com/2012/10/simple-tcp-forwarder-in-c.html

Comment: @BitTickler- Request is need to forward request as well as send the response back to client. I modified this code as per my requirement just to check if this code can handle large threads per second on receive but it result same.